# Работа с ini файлом

Tags: java

У меня есть .ini файл. Метод для работы с ним уже написал. Там key=value. В value у меня строка. Возможно ли вывести ее с переносом(\n)?

К примеру, в файле у меня key=Перенос\nстроки
и мне нужно чтобы вывело:

Перенос

строки

Делаю так

```
protected Map<String, String> loadLang(String lang) {
    try {
        String content = Utils.readFile(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("lang/"+lang+".ini"));
        Map<String, String> d = new HashMap<>();
        for (String line : content.split("\n")) {
            line = line.trim();
            if (line.equals("") || line.charAt(0) == '#') {
                continue;
            }
            String[] t = line.split("=");
            if (t.length < 2) {
                continue;
            }
            String key = t[0];
            String value = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < t.length - 1; i++) {
                value += t[i] + "=";
            }
            value += t[t.length - 1];
            if (value.equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            d.put(key, value);
        }
        return d;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Server.getInstance().getLogger().logException(e);
        return null;
    }
}
Далее this.languages().get(key); мне выведет value. В котором и нужно реализовать перенос строки
```

Comment: вывести строку куда?

Comment: Ну хотя бы в консоль

Comment: println() не пробывали?

Comment: а почему ini. а не properties? и почему сами пишите, а не используете готовую библиотеку?

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Замените последовательность символов `\n`, на перевод строки.

```
String str = "test\\ntest";
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(str.replace("\\n", "\n"));
```

Вывод

> test\ntest
>   test
>   test

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш способ помог

Comment: тогда принимайте ответ. и лучше возьмите готовую библиотеку для работы с файлами http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/